# momentary to on/off switch for 12v

Tags: switches, flipflop, 12v, latch

I got some oem switches and I want to mod them into light switches.

Here is my situation:

I would like to use the oem switch since it has illumination and button that matches the car.I have already located the illuminations and found out the switch is momentary.

I'd want them to operated as on/off switches.
Here is the diagram for the lights and the included switch: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6569565/Forester/2014-12-09%20201.jpg

The momentary switch has 2 wires, but the included switch has 3, + - and ground.

So far I've found latch relay and ic jk flip flop would work, but they are too complex (I can't seem to find the right diagram for my needs). Are there any pre made relay for my purpose, 12v?

---

Edit by [Kamil](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/39905/kamil):

I've found this one on the net, but it's for 5V: [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#%24+1+5.0E-6+10.20027730826997+50+5.0+50%0AR+480+80+560+80+0+0+40.0+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Ag+480+368+576+368+0%0A156+288+176+352+176+0+0.0%0Aw+480+80+256+80+0%0As+80+80+80+160+0+1+true%0Aw+288+208+192+208+0%0Aw+80+208+80+160+0%0Ad+96+208+192+208+1+0.805904783%0Aw+96+208+80+208+0%0Aw+288+240+240+240+0%0Aw+240+240+240+224+0%0Aw+240+224+256+224+0%0Aw+256+224+256+192+0%0Aw+256+192+240+192+0%0Aw+240+192+240+176+0%0Aw+240+176+240+96+0%0Aw+256+80+240+80+0%0Aw+240+80+240+96+0%0Aw+240+80+80+80+0%0Aw+288+176+240+176+0%0Aw+80+208+80+288+0%0Ar+80+288+80+368+0+10000.0%0Ar+80+288+192+288+0+470.0%0Aw+192+208+192+288+0%0Ac+192+288+192+368+0+1.0000000000000001E-7+1.2419659145158052E-49%0Aw+80+368+192+368+0%0Aw+192+368+288+368+0%0Aw+288+368+480+368+0%0Aw+384+176+480+176+0%0A162+480+176+480+368+1+2.1024259+1.0+0.0+0.0%0Ao+0+64+0+35+5.0+0.2+0+-1%0A)

and can someone list the parts that are in this circuit?

Mainly the spec for the jk flipflop? For 12v tho.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.com! You can edit your question instead of posting "answer" below, and use "link" function to hide that big ugly url. I fixed that for you because you are new. Here u have some help: [link] (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) (see part "Improve posts by editing or commenting")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not use a relay but a FET, seems to tolerate your voltage needs (from 4.5V to 20V). You have to check if 10A max is ok for your application.

http://www.pololu.com/product/750

If you bypass the push button with your momentary switch you should have what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I am still a little confused.

my original wire harness has a positive negative and a ground, so If I add this to my assembly, how would I connect the ground because there are 2? Do I connect both to the same ground?

I see there are 2 V in and V out. Do I just use one?